# Use ffmpeg to stream rawvideo from a USB camera

Tags: ffmpeg, video, windows, linux, raw

I have a image sensor that streams 640x480 in RAW8 format. A USB controller is receiving this data, packing two pixels of 8-bits each and sending to USB as a 16-bits per pixel YUV422 format (this is because currently UVC does not support RAW8 format).

I was checking if I can use ffmpeg to receive the UVC stream and decode it as RAW8 video.

Has anyone tried this before?

Comment: How do you access the sensor? With UVC?

Comment: Yes. its a UVC class device.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video0
```

you can query all available formats and resolutions

With

```
ffplay -f video4linux2 -input_format raw -i /dev/video0
```

you can access the raw video stream of the UVC device

Comment: Thanks for your reply!


I am using Windows and was able to stream RAW8 video by reporting the pixel_format  as gray.

( I used  ffmpeg -f dshow -pix_fmt gray -video_size 1280x720 -i video="UVC" -f nut - |  fplay -flags low_delay - )


However, I do not see any way to stream RAW10. I am not sure which pixel_format to use in this case. Do you know? 

Thanks!

Comment: What output do `-pix_fmts` and `-list_formats` show?